# CMake cross compile - separate invocation per platform?

Tags: cmake, clang, cross-compiling

I'm new to CMake, which I'm using to cross-compile.

I'm using clang and [wclang](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/wclang) together, under Debian, to compile for Linux and Windows respectively.

My question - since I'm new to CMake's cross compile process - is do I:

(a) switch between compilers somewhere during CMakeLists.txt,

(b) run `cmake` only once, but `make install` for each platform, or

(c) run `cmake` and `make install` once for each platform, e.g.

`$ export CC=/usr/bin/clang
$ cmake ..
$ make install`

`$ export CC=/usr/bin/wclang
$ cmake ..
$ make install`

(etc.)

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C), separate invocation per platform. I would also recommend clearing the binary directory between builds, or using a separate directory for each build if you want to preserve the build(s).

Settings are usually done in a *toolchain file*, not the command line (for reproducability):

```
$ cmake --help-variable CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
--------------------

Path to toolchain file supplied to ``cmake(1)``.

This variable is specified on the command line when cross-compiling with CMake.
It is the path to a file which is read early in the CMake run and which specifies
locations for compilers and toolchain utilities, and other target platform and
compiler related information.
```

A simple toolchain file can look like this:

```
# Name of the target operating system
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows )

# Which compilers to use
find_program( CMAKE_C_COMPILER   NAMES /opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-gcc )
find_program( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER NAMES x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-g++ )
find_program( CMAKE_RC_COMPILER  NAMES x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-windres )

# Where to look for resources
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/ )

# Adjust find_*() behavior:
# Headers and libs from the target environment,
# programs from the host environment.
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY )
```

Some cross-compiling environments, like [MXE](http://mxe.cc), come with pre-made toolchain files and wrappers calling them. (MXE in particular, you run `i686-w64-mingw32.static-cmake` instead of standard `cmake` to configure your build.)

Comment: Does this approach (c) require a separate target name for each platform being built? Otherwise CMake generates just one (set of) makefile(s) across the board, instead of one for each platform; at that point I don't know how to differentiate builds.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: I do not understand your question. You create a directory, e.g. `project-Linux`, and therein build your project for the Linux target. Then you create a *different* directory, e.g. `project-Windows`, and therein build your project for the Windows target. It should be pretty easy to tell the builds apart...? If you `cpack` them, you even get the system name as part of the package filename...

Comment: Aha, OK. I was using a single folder thus far just to get CMake working _per se_ (which your answer helped me to do). Now that it is, I should probably differentiate folder-wise as you suggest. Thanks again.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: I am still not sure I can follow your line of thinking. Standard CMake procedure is to have *one* source tree, which does *not* get touched or any files added to during a build. You do the build (or several builds) in a *separate* directory / directories.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: May I be so bold as to advertise [JAWS](http://jaws.rootdirectory.de), a ready-to-go CMake configuration framework? It's not finished yet, but I think it can give a good idea of what can be done with CMake.

Comment: I have a folder, `/test`. In there I have a source file `main.c`, a `CMakeLists.txt`, a `win.toolchain.cmake`, a `linux.toolchain.cmake` and a `cross.sh`, which contains my approach (c) from the OQ. Be there dragons?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112886/discussion-between-devsolar-and-arcane-engineer).

Answer (score 1):

All steps (cmake - make - install) should be repeated for every target. That is, "c" in your list.

---

Some development environments, e.g. Visual Studio, support *multi configuration*, that is project can be *configured once*, and every target configuration requires just *building*. Such a way project can be compiled in Debug and Release mode, or for x86 and x86-64.

But Windows and Linux targets require distinct configuration step (`cmake` run) in any case.